# Validate json values in response body before sending to spring controller to avoid response code 400

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, response

My Spring controller accepts application json response body as an object parameter. I don't see where I can intercept the json to validate the values before Spring controller receives it and complains when it doesn't cast.

Example: User sends json to endpoint - /createUser

Expecting: {"username":"johndoe", "pin": 1234}
Receives: {"username": 1234, "pin": "johndoe"}

If string is sent for int or vice versa, server will show status 400.  I'd like to validate the data myself and provide a custom json that details the values that are incorrectly set.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you mean that you want to validate your `@RequestBody` param, right? if that, you could try [validation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-validation) or creating [your own validator](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator).

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly.  I was thinking about the problem the wrong way.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create your own class for the `@RequestBody` param in your controller and make a validation on them. You could use some supported annotations or create on your own. But don't forget to put the `@Valid` next to the `@RequestBody`, that's the key. E.g

```java
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @PostMapping("/users")
    ResponseEntity<String> addUser(@Valid @RequestBody User user) {
        // persisting the user
        return ResponseEntity.ok("User is valid");
    }
    
    // standard constructors / other methods
    
}
```

For more information, you could find them here [validation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-validation), [create your own validator](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator).